# How to implement different `std::map insert()` behaviour depending on the existence of the pair being inserted?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap, insertion

I'd like the `std::map insert()` function to behave differently depending on whether the pair to insert is already in the map or not - if it is not, insert it as usual, if it is already there, increment the counter stored inside a `second` of the pair. How can I do that without additional querying the existence (since the insertion queries it anyway)?

I'm tracking a lot of event records, each of them containing the `source` and `receiver` ID's. Events are stored as `std::vector`. I'm also trying to maintain the dictionary of `sources` and `receivers` records as `std::map` where the `first` of the pair (key) contains the ID, while the `second` contains some `source` info plus `std::vector` that tracks all the events that refer to that `source`.

So, when the event refers to currently absent `source`, the insertion should proceed as normal, but if the referred `source` is already in the dictionary, the insertion should add the referring event number to `std::vector` of the existing dictionary element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one have to keep the result of the `insert` function, analyse it and behave accordingly:

```
typedef std::map<int, T> itmap;
typedef std::pair<itmap::iterator, bool> itinsresult;
//...
itmap m;
int i;
T t;
//...
itinsresult result = m.insert(std::make_pair(i, t));
if (result.second) // new element inserted
{
   //...
}
else // element already exists
{
   (*result.first).do_something();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: `->` added to the language especially to avoid convoluted `(*result.first).do_something()`